# Can't run SSRS ReportBuilder 1.0 from multiple sites

Tags: clickonce, reportbuilder

We have a UAT Reporting Services website, and a corresponding Production site, where both sites allow the user to use the ClickOnce install of SSRS ReportBuilder 1.0 so that they can design their own reports. The versions of ReportBuilder.exe are identical.

The problem we get is that if a user runs ReportBuilder from one site, and then attempts to run ReportBuilder from the other site, the second attempt fails with the message

> Unable to install this application because an application with the
>   same identity is already installed. To install this application,
>   either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall
>   the preexisting application.

The message is pretty clear about the two options. However for a 3rd party app like ReportBuilder, I don't think option 1 is available since the deployment manifest is strong-named.

Option 2 is a dirty hack, which is not the sort of thing I like to tell users that they have to do whenever they want to change between sites. But this seems to me to be the only way.

Has anyone else struck this issue? If so, were you also reduced to deleting the installed version before you could install the same version from another site?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the Click Once Application Cache.

I closed the browser, ran the command, tried again and all worked fine. The command was

```
rundll dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
```

Comment: Do not post only links to help someone, because links are not permanent!

Comment: This is Option 2. I use it myself, but the problem is that it's no good for users who are using locked-down PCs and don't have rights to run command line.